# Which integers from a set of integers to XOR to make a target integer?

Tags: algorithm, xor

Given is:

- A set of about 800 pseudo-random unsigned 64-bit integers.

  ```
  2910088619203924111,  8611579852607706360,  10743563285097812384,
  6712886796489718596, 17298387234720051377,  12467698534877227789,
  3782074590599432740,  1419307814092336225,   7951308495700413025,
  ...
  ```
- A target integer `17358988457627394926` of the same kind, in most cases not in the set.

It is guaranteed that the target integer was made by XORing a subset of up to 50 (or less) integers of the set together.

What is the most efficient algorithm to find a subset (any, not nescessarily the smallest) of integers that make the target integer when XORed?

If NP-hard, what would be a basic idea to prove it?

Comment: I retract my last comment...if all you want is *a* solution (not the *best* solution), it's not NP-hard.

Comment: @nneonneo: Thanks. I clarified in the question that any solution would suffice.

Comment: Is this problem related to encryption?  Can you provide an example of how and why you manage to have the target integer that is the result of an xor operation from a set of values in an array.  Do you have an idea on how to apply Gaussian elimimination to this problem?

Comment: @BobBryan: Yes. I've been playing with writing a chess library in python. For efficient lookups Zobrist-hashes can be used as identifiers for positions. See https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/master/chess/zobrist_hasher.py#L221 for a sample implementation. I was wondering if I can reverse that hash function.

Comment: Since it appears that you have access to the code to the hash function, as a practical matter can't the indexes in the hash function simply be stored into an array that can be used later to easily retrieve them?  If you need these frequently, then it would most likely be much more efficient to do it this way.

I suspect that using Gaussian elimination might be straight forward if you have used it before, but if not, then it will be difficult to implement.  Perhaps @nneonneo can provide you with some code examples if you really want to go down that path.

Comment: @BobBryan: That's not possible, because I might want to reverse some hash from an opening book I have never seen. (Those opening books are not designed for that way of lookup - so this is an unusual problem.) I think I'll be able to implement the gaussian elimination. I'll post back here, once I've done that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working in Z<sub>2</sub>, the problem is equivalent to finding a solution to the matrix equation `Ax = b`, where `A` is the 64x800 binary matrix formed by taking the binary expansion of each element and `b` is the 64-element binary matrix representing the solution.

Such a system is quite easy to solve using straightforward Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a simple yet powerful insight that ({0, 1}, XOR) forms a group.